# Wordpress permalinks with a load balancer in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, wordpress, permalinks

Hello I used the wordpress one click deploy on google cloud and am trying to get custom permalinks working but every setting besides the default gives me a 502 server error.

My load balancer is setup with this frontend IP, 35.241.50.51
My backend IP is 34.69.91.228

My domain, hexcards.io,  is set to the google name servers and I have a zone in the cloud dns which is pointing to the load balancer frontend IP, 35.241.50.51

Google gave me an SSL certificate and it is working fine with the load balancer.

In wordpress my site address and wordpress address are both set to, https://hexcards.io

Basically everything works fine until I try to switch permalinks which then gives me a 502 server error even in the wordpress admin.

- Can Wordpress permalinks work with a load balancer?
- How do I view 502 server errors with google cloud?  It's apache 2.0+
- Is there a website where I can hire a google cloud & wordpress expert to help me?

EDIT:

I didn't configure apache, it was setup automatically with the wordpress one click deploy that google cloud has.  I checked the apache2.conf file and there is no virtualhost directive.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
PHP 7.4.24 (cli)
Wordpress is up to date

Comment: Your problem is not caused by Google Cloud. This is an Apache configuration problem. Edit your question and show how you configured Apache. Most likely you have a permissions issue with the VirtualHost **Directory** directive. Include the version of OS, Apache, WordPress and PHP. Saying Apache 2.0+ is not enough. There are large differences between Apache 2.0, 2.2 and 2.4.

Comment: I updated it John, thx

Comment: A 5xx error is the way of the webserver saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Read the error logs of your webserver, they will contain a clear message what's wrong.

Comment: Thx Gerald, do you know how I can read them?  I read the error.log but it didn't show any errors

Comment: You should be able to find the logs in Google Cloud Logging. However, this depends on how your system is configured. I recommend that you read the documentation written by the vendor of the **click to deploy** application or contact them for support. Without details, we can only guess.